# angular: ¿como acceder a la propiedad de un FormGroup?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formularios, map

**Contexto**

Tengo un formulario reactivo en angular:

```
patientForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    address: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    day: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    month: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    year: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    phone: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    reason: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  });
```

Pero yo quiero acceder a alguno de los controles, por ejemplo quiero acceder a lo que el usuario escribio en "month" ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?

//Estaba haciendo algo como esto, pero hasta alli me quede

```
 this.place = this.patientForm.setValue({
        address: ''
      })
```

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Realmente les agradeceria su ayuda, me ando desvelando por ando buscando documentacion de algun ejemplo como este, pero no he encontrado. Porfavor.

Comment: `this.patientForm.get('month').value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios modos de acceder a los datos de tus FormControls:

- Angular tiene una clase abstracta que se llama [`AbstractControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl). De esta clase extienden las clases `FormArray`, `FormControl` y `FormGroup`.

  Por tanto, todas ellas tienen el atributo de solo lectura `value`. Si compruebas este valor de un FormControl, obtendrás el valor de ese control. Si lo hace de un FormGroup, obtendrás un objeto con la estructura de tu FormGroup: las claves (nombres de los atributos serán los nombres de los FormControls<sup>1</sup> internos y los valores serán los de dichos FormControls

En tu caso:

```js
let data = this.patientForm.value;
// data = {
//   name: '...',
//   address: '...',
//   day: '...',
//   ....
// }
```

- De manera similar, podrías, sabiendo el nombre del FormControl contenido, acceder directamente así:

```js
let name = this.patientForm['name'].value; 
// this.patientForm.name?.value valdría también, pero TS te va a mostrar *Warnings* 
// porque name no está formalmente definido para la clase FormGroup
```

- Pero es más aconsejable usar el método [`get`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get):

```
let name = this.patientForm.get('name').value;
```

Notas:
<sup>1</sup> Un `FormGroup` puede tener dentro otros objetos `FormGroup` o `FormArray` anidados, con lo que obtendrías un objeto con varios niveles de profundidad.

Comment: Mil gracias, me ayudaste mucho, entendi mejor que en la documentación. Nuevamente gracias